# Devolucion incorrecta del dia en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy recuperando el dia actual con javascript pero este me duelve otro numero que es totalmente incorrecto

```
let date = new Date();
    console.log(date.getDay());
```

ese el el formato correcto de solisitar el dia?

Comment: dia del mes calendario? Día de la semana? día del año? Dia desde `UNIX epoch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruben para tomar el valor del día actual tienes que solicitarlo de la siguiente manera

```
  console.log(date.getDate());
```

Obtendrás los días de 1 a 31

De la manera que tu lo estas solicitando obtendrás el valor del día de la semana enumerado del 0 a 6, comprendes?

Por ejemplo hoy sábado será numero 6